# What will be the time complexity, when the location of the element is given?

Tags: data-structures, operating-system

Given an array of n elements, what is the time complexity to get an element at location i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant time will be taken so ,

```
Time complexity is O(1).
```

Array are collection of the contiguous memory location, so you need to add the index to the base address and it will take constant time.

```
arr[i] is equal to the *(arr+i)
```

so adding i to the base address, will take constant time.

Answer (score 0):

An array element can be **directly** accessed in constant time i. e. O(1).